# wix installer log message - Unable to remove cached package

Tags: wix

Can you please help me with the following:

I have installed an installer on my VM. after then i installed an upgraded version of the same installer.

For some reason, i got an error message during the upgrade.

That is not my point!  My point is, after i got the error message, i pressed "ok" to continue on aborting the upgrade.

it started rolling back, but got stuck at certain point.

the log file showed some error on some element: "Unable to remove cached package".

The code contains 2 ExePackages which implement the same package cache directory, and while it rolled back, it removed one of these elements cache directory.

when the rolling back reached the second element, it searched for the same cached directory, and couldnt find it.

Is there a way that, while creating, could i force to implement in a different cache directory?

Answer (score 0):

The cache directory can be overridden with the [ExePackage](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/exepackage.html) `CacheId` attribute.

I use this in one of the installers I've authored to know the cache location of some MSI that use `<Product Id="*" .../>`. Just make sure if you use this CacheId attribute you set it to a value that you know won't be the same between two builds to avoid the problem you're currently facing.